# A tag is supposed to open a new window,but it didn't work with ieDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver

There is a problem that I used to meet: When I used c#&selenium to manipulate Internet explorer, a A tag that was supposed to open a new window,but it didn't work when I clicked on it using ieDriver simulation.Shut down ieDriver, and it works successufully.My level is limited, so I want to ask for help here...

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
webDriver.Url = "http://emp.sc.ctc.com/#/app/reference/home";
//any website that contains elememt like <a id="1" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click</a>
...
IWebElement webElement = webDriver.FindElementByXpath(By.Xpath("//*[@id=\"1\"]"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);
```

Just these simple operations.The webElement is `<a id="1" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click</a>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<a id="1" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">click</a>

</body>
</html>
```

,which was supposed to open a new browser window.

Comment: Please provide any code you have that's relevant to your question.

Comment: Update these within the main question and add the relevant HTML

Comment: ~how to update my posted questions...

Comment: click on edit and update the content

Comment: @SilentWatson Your _...simplified the situation..._ may not really help the contributors to construct a canonical answer to your question. Instead update the question with text based relevant actual HTML.

Comment: My intention in simplifying the scenario is to highlight the core problem: using selenium's ieDriver to manipulate ie to click on the element <a>, which should open a new browser window, but it doesn't.It doesn't help to do it manually at the same time.However, if ieDriver. exe is closed manually at this time, then manually clicking <a> element can achieve the desired effect.It is also easy to reproduce the problem and eliminate other nonsense code which may confuse or distract others from the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem through painful reflection.The desired effect can be achieved simply by running vs with administrator privileges, or by running the compiled program with administrator privileges.So it's not a **code** problem, it's an **environmental** problem.ieDriver is not responsible for this.